# Port an OpenLayers application to mobile devices

Tags: mobile, openlayers

After making a duration/cost estimation, I'm about to start developing a desktop application using OpenLayers. I've never had experience on it before, but have the support of some coworkers who do.

Now we have to estimate the time and effort it would take the same application to be viewable in mobile devices. I know the existence of `openlayers.mobile.js`, but nobody in my company has ever worked with it before.

I know it has some advantages over the *normal* OpenLayers library, such as pinching for zooming, and so. But, does it has any blocked capabilities? I mean, if I write code to draw a line on a layer in the desktop application, change the simbology of a layer, add a buffer arround a polyline, etc..  will it still work with the mobile library?

Is there funcionality in the desktop version that is not in the mobile one?

I'd need to know before estimating what can I offer in the mobile version, and how hard will it be to get so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See examples tagged with mobile:

- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/

The [next OpenLayer versions](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/) will probably have better mobile support as this is something many users are interested in.